# Trait self type bound: A with B but not A with C

Tags: scala

Say I have:

```
abstract class D[T] {}
trait A[T] { self => D[T] without B }
trait B[T] { self => D[T] without A }
```

Bottom line, `B` cannot be mixed into D if it already extends `A`.

```
class Test extends D[String] with B[String] // ok
class Test2 extends D[String] with A[String] // ok
class Test3 extends D[String] with A[String] with B[whatever] // bad
class Test4 extends D[String] with B[String] with A[whatever] // bad
```

How can I correctly enforce this type bound?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a way to do this, though I don't know if it's the only / preferred way.

```
sealed trait Z[T <: Z[T]]
trait A extends Z[A] { this: D => }
trait B extends Z[B] { this: D => }

scala> new D with A
res6: D with A = $anon$1@7e7584ec

scala> new D with B
res7: D with B = $anon$1@7537e98f

scala> new D with A with B
<console>:15: error: illegal inheritance;
 anonymous class $anon inherits different type instances of trait Z:
Z[B] and Z[A]
              new D with A with B
                  ^
```

Comment: Tricky :) But I don't understand why you sealed `trait Z` and why you added that bound on `T` (`T <: Z[T]`). I tried without these and it worked too. Maybe some cases I didn't foresee?

Comment: @Dimitri It doesn't work without the type bound, the bound is the trick as it changes the signature. `sealed` is not necessary but it fits the question perfectly, as you don't want to expose a trait used only to enforce bounds.

Comment: I'd say this is a long way to go to work around the monotonicity of type definitions in Scala. And anything that gives the OP what he wants is going to violate the LSP.

Comment: I agree with you Randall. I just wanted to show it's possible ;-)